# Validation Engine Match Field

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i'm using jQuery.validationEngine to match Password and Confirm Password fields.

```
<input value="" class="validate[required,custom[password]] text-input" type="password" name="txtpswd" id="txtpswd" />
<input value="" class="validate[required,equals[txtpswd]] text-input" type="password" name="password2" id="password2" />
```

Above code is working fine.
But:
First Problem:while i use runat="server" in anyone/both(input tag) of them then it fails matching. 
Second Problem:while i use server controls(textbox) in lieu of html input tag, then it fails matching.
Please tell me where i'm wrong? Please help me to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to check **confirm password** validation, then you can use like this.

```
<input type="password" id="password" name="password"  class="validate[required]"/>
<input type="password" id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password"  class="validate[required,equals[password]]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this porperty to your server control. ClientIDMode="Static"

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtpswd" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="validate[required,custom[password]] text-input"></asp:TextBox>
```